# Moser iteration technique

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A short and simple (or maybe not so much) question, what's the general idea of the moser iteration technique and how does it work? I have seen some papers on it but I haven't really yet understood the idea of it... Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Moser's papers (the elliptic ones at least) are beautiful and highly readable; I suggest just looking through them.

Comment: Maybe I looked at the wrong ones until now...do you have the names of the papers you are referring to?

Comment: A google search provides many articles on Moser iteration technique. Here's one. I hope it will be helpful. https://users.math.msu.edu/users/sutravek/PMI.pdf

Comment: Great, thanks for your help!

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1002/cpa.3160130308

https://doi.org/10.1002/cpa.3160140329

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the overall goal of Moser iteration is relatively easy to understand and is best motivated in the context of trying to prove a Harnack inequality. Indeed, Moser introduced as a refinement of De-Giorgi's proof of the De Giorgi-Nash-Moser theorem which proves a Harnack inequality for uniformly elliptic PDE in divergence form with only bounded coefficients.

Let $u$ be a nonnegative solution of $\mathrm{div}(A(x)\nabla u) =0$ in $B_1$ with $A$ uniformly elliptic and bounded. Say we want to prove the Harnack inequality, that is, $$\tag{1}\sup_{B_{1/2}} u \leqslant C \inf_{B_{1/2}}u $$ with $C$ depending only on $n$ and $A$. The is best done in two parts: *local boundedness* (also called the mean-value inequality) $$ \tag{2} \sup_{B_{1/2}}u\leqslant C\| u\|_{L^2(B_1)}  $$ the *weak Harnack inequality* $$\|u\|_{L^2(B_1)} \leqslant  \inf_{B_{1/2}}u \tag{3} $$ I think it is clear that $(2)$ and $(3)$ immediately imply $(1)$. The idea of Moser iteration is to take advantage of the fact that $$ \lim_{p \to \infty} \| u\|_{L^p(B_r)} = \sup_{B_r}u \text{ and } \lim_{p \to -\infty} \| u\|_{L^p(B_r)} = \inf_{B_r}u, \tag{$\ast$} $$ so $L^p$ norms interpolate between the infimum and the supremum of $u$. Hence, if we can show an estimate such as $$ \bigg (  \int_{B_{1/2}} u^{\gamma q } \, dx \bigg )^{\frac 1{\gamma q}}  \leqslant \bigg (   C  \int_{B_{1/2}} u^q \, dx \bigg )^{\frac1q} \tag{4}$$ for some $\gamma>1$ and all $q\geqslant 2$ with $C$ independent of $q$ then we have proven $(2)$ since we can just iterate $k$ times to obtain $\| u \|_{L^{2\gamma^k}(B_{1/2})}\leqslant C \|u\|_{L^2(B_{1/2})}\leqslant C \|u\|_{L^2(B_1)}$ then send $k\to \infty$. However, for scaling reasons, such an inequality cannot be possible, so we have to be a bit smarter. Instead, what Moser does, is prove the inequality $$ \bigg (  \int_{B_{s}} u^{\gamma q } \, dx \bigg )^{\frac 1{\gamma q}}  \leqslant \bigg (   \frac C {\vert t-s\vert^2}  \int_{B_{t}} u^q \, dx \bigg )^{\frac1q} \tag{5} $$ with $\gamma = \frac n{n-2}>1$ and $0<s<t\leqslant 1$ (and $C$ independent of $s$ and $t$), that is, he proves that (4) is true provided that we increase the radius of the ball in the integral on the right-hand side. Then he takes a strictly decreasing sequence of radii $\{r_k\}$ such that $r_1=1$, $r_k \to 1/2$, and $r_k-r_{k+1}\geqslant 2^{-k-2}$, say, $r_k = \frac 12 + 2^{-k-1}$ and uses (5) with $s=r_{k+1}$, $t=r_k$, and $q=2\gamma^{k-1}$ to obtain \begin{align*} \| u\|_{L^{2\gamma^k }(B_{r_{k+1}})} &=\bigg (  \int_{B_{r_{k+1}}} u^{2\gamma^k  } \, dx \bigg )^{\frac 1{2\gamma^k }} \\
&\leqslant \bigg (    C^k   \int_{B_{r_k}} u^{2\gamma^{k-1}} \, dx \bigg )^{\frac1{2\gamma^{k-1}}} \\
&= C^{\frac{k}{\gamma^{k-1}}}\| u\|_{L^{2\gamma^{k-1}}(B_{r_k})}\leqslant \cdots \leqslant C \| u\|_{L^2(B_1)} . \end{align*} Thus, sending $k \to \infty$ gives $(2)$.

The idea to prove $(3)$ is, in principle, exactly the same (iterate between $L^p$ norm with ball of different radii), but slightly more technical because you have to deal with $L^p$ norm with negative powers.

So, to conclude, Moser iteration is simply a family of inequalities between $L^p$ norms of increasing powers which, via ($\ast$), allows us to connect the infimum of our function to its supremum.

Comment: Thank you very much! This explanation made it very clear indeed. I have never seen negative exponents with $L^p$ norms though.

Comment: I find it somewhat strange that the $L^p$ exponent basically sitting in the middle of the Harnack inequality is exactly $2$. Is there a "simple" reasoning why exactly $2$ is the natural exponent here?

Comment: Great observation. Short answer is literally nothing is special about $p=2$, I chose it for simplicity. If you check out Gilbarg and Trudinger Ch8 then you’ll see that they do it for any $p$